# background colour not showing in some devices

Tags: css

I used a background colour in css. Some devices its not showing. Css color is given below. Is that issue with browser? why this issue is happen please check

```
background-color: #06060638;
```

Comment: @ Horacio Coronel  thx for your reply. that is a transparent color . is this a browser related issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format #RRGGBBAA [(*8 digits hexadecimal notation*)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#hex-notation) is quite recent (I think it has been introduced in the *CCS Module Level 4*), and all browsers didn't jumped in yet.

You might be better keep using the `rgba` notation, which is widely supported.

```css
body{
  background: rgba(6, 6, 6, 0.22);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hexadecimal color values are supported in all browsers.
>   [look here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hexadecimal.asp)

A hexadecimal color is specified with: #RRGGBB.
Typically has "6" numbers following the #

like this: #000000
Other color formats are     `rgb(0,0,0)`, `hsl(0, 100%, 50%)` and `Black

There is an issue with your hex color code. you can visit adobe color picker and find a color and it will give you hex or rgb, be sure to properly copy, paste the code. https://color.adobe.com/